# Missed call alerts when phone busy on another call?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, samsung-galaxy-y, missed-calls

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y phone with Gingerbread.

I have just discovered that I do not receive any kind of missed call notifications when my phone is busy on another call.

I am quite shocked as this facility is available even in very cheap, ordinary phones.

How do I fix it? Is it because of some phone settings of mine? or is there an android update? or do I need to install some app? or is the trouble with my network operator?

Comment: If your operator permits call waiting and if you enable it, the second incoming call if not attended will be taken as a missed call.  Some operators will provide it as a free service (in most cases), but it is left to the operator to charge a fixed small amount on monthly basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Call settings -> Additional settings** and find **Call Waiting** option (its may be in different address in android 2.3).

Enable **Call Waiting** it if is not already. If it was already enabled, but you never here beeps or receive notifications when another call happens, I think you should check with or consult your operator.